How to use for loops in Lua / Roblox?
I am trying to make it so that the items that are in the player's backpack appears on the sell Ui, the problem is that I don't know where to start.
Here is the code shown:
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local pack = player.Backpack
local itemSell = script.Parent.Item1
local items = pack:GetChildren()

for i = 1, #items do

end

The blank space is where I got stumped. How can I make it work?

You can iterate for each key or child in items and then for each one, create a button.
In the below code, for each item in items we will create a TextButton. If the user presses the TextButton, then print that the user wants to sell an item.
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local pack = player.Backpack
local itemSell = script.Parent.Item1
local items = pack:GetChildren()

-- Function to create a button given a tool
local function addItem(item: Tool): ()
    local newButton = Instance.new("TextButton")
    newButton.Name = item.Name
    newButton.Text = item.Name
    newButton.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
        print(player.Name " wants to sell " .. item.Name) -- Username wants to sell item name
    end)
    newButton.Parent = workspace -- Change this to the frame you want the buttons parented to
end

-- Loop through each item and create a button for each
for _, item: Tool in pairs(items) do
    addItem(item)
end

Make sure to replace the newButton's parent with the Frame that you want the buttons to appear in instead of workspace or they won't appear at all.
If you have any questions on the code or explanation on some parts feel free to comment on what does what.

What do you mean by "Change this to the frame you want the buttons parented to", when I tested it won't work and I did change the workspace to the frame.

@skisp The buttons need a parent, ideally a Frame with UIListLayout so that the buttons are in a list.

So I changed the button's parent but doesn't seem to work, I did everything that is done in that script. This script it located in StarterGui.Folder.ScreenGui.ImageIabel.ScrollingFrame. What am I doing wrong? @Ryan Luu

@skisp You likely one of the variables you have are incorrect but to answer your initial question you can use a loop to create a button for each item by creating a function which creates a button given an item and then iterating through each item with that function using a for i, v in pairs loop.

I'm making it where if the player gain an item by completing a task, the item frame is applied, how is it not working? @Ryan Luu
